# Prepositions that precede infinitives

Tags: traducción, gramática, vocabulario

I have seen often in Spanish prepositions precede infinitives where no preposition is translated in English. For example, 'Es importante aprender **a escribir**, or "Estoy emocionado **de trabajar** para Tim", or " Necesitas estudiar **para ser inteligente.**" When do you need a preposition before an infinitive, and which preposition when? Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions are notoriously idiosyncratic. Often there is no apparent logic to them. They must be learned together with the verbs or adjectives they tend to accompany. They cannot be freely translated from one language to another, and you should not expect Spanish to coincide with English in this respect.

In your examples you refer to infinitives, so you're probably wondering why *learn to write* translates as *aprender a escribir* and so on. Now, the fact that *to* is used to mark infinitives in English shouldn't obscure the fact that *to* is also a preposition, and is clearly acting like one in *study to be smart*.

The other two examples are doubtful. In *learn to write*, the phrase *to write* can be interpreted as the infinitive acting as the direct object of the verb, in which case you're right (English just uses the infinitive while Spanish needs a preposition before it). If so, then it's just a matter of different grammars. But note that you could use *learn writing*, with the *-ing* form as the direct object, parallel to *learn mathematics*, but you mostly don't; this suggests that *learn to write* is not parallel to *learn mathematics*, and *to write* is not a unit, but simply a combination of preposition + verb.

One thing that gives this away is that in other cases, other prepositions are used with a gerund for essentially the same kind of construction: *used for serving dessert*; *charged with caring for the children*; etc. English also uses *to* with gerunds in *he was used to sleeping until late*.

The main difference between the languages, therefore, is that Spanish uses a lot of prepositions with a single form of the verb (the infinitive), while English uses mostly one preposition (*to*) with the base form of the verb, and the rest of the prepositions with another form (the gerund or *-ing* form). Spanish doesn't use its gerunds with prepositions at all.

Coming to your question at last: there's no comprehensive list of which preposition goes with each verb, and we couldn't give it here anyway (this is for specific questions, not to ask for lists). You'll need to see which goes with which as you find them. One thing that can be noted is that Spanish doesn't use its infinitives without prepositions much. They don't take prepositions when they're the subject of a sentence, of course, but then when subordinated to other verbs or adjectives they almost take one, except in a few cases, like the perception verbs *ver*, *parecer*, *oír*, etc., and the emotion verbs *creer*, *temer*, *odiar*, etc., as well as *acostumbrar* and *soler*.

- *veo caer la lluvia*
- *parece estar muerto*
- *se oye tronar*
- *creo haber dicho que...*
- *temo enterarme*
- *odio ir al cine*
- *se acostumbra cenar temprano*
- *solemos tomar café*

Comment: Eh teeeeechnically (you know I'd be the one to find an obscure rule haha) you can use the gerund in Spanish with a preposition but only one: *en*. Vastly less common today, though, than it used to be